# Java HTTP calls in Firebase Realtime Database for data changes in a software

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I developed a software in JAVA language for Windows that needs to check Firebase Realtime Database data changes by HTTP calls.

Now, i have a thing like that:

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run() {
                 checkNewValues();                
            }
        }, 0, 500);
```

In **CheckNewValues();** there's a normal HTTP get call.

**My question is:** is there a better way to do it? (**there's a better way to do it for sure I think**) I mean, in Firebase SDK we can set **Listeners** and use the **OnDataChange** but I don't have any idea how to simplify the whole process here without SDK, so, is there a similar way to do it without SDK? would be nice any suggestion or help.

**Thank you in advance, happy coding to everyone! :)**

Comment: If you would use spring you could use `@Scheduled` or if you would use cloud functions you could do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DglTSNEdl0U&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=8&t=0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't just use the Firebase Admin SDK, which is available for Java/JVM and which makes this type of work simple.

But if you insist on doing this with a Firebase SDK, the closest you can get to the same behavior is by calling the [Firebase Realtime Database's REST **Streaming** API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming). Similar to the Firebase SDKs, this API immediately gives you the current data at a location, and then gives you updates as they occur on the server. This means you'll only have attach a listener to the correct REST endpoint once, and don't need to poll for changes.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what i was looking for, again, thank you very much, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is opinion based and can be closed that's why.

What is "better way"?

- Better from implementation time? Then your approach can be the best one.
- Better from the performance point of view? Then you approach can be the worst one.
- Better from the point of view of data transferred via network? In some cases (if database change not often) you approach can be bad, because you trigger unneeded calls, in other (if database changes much more often than your code checks it), your approach can be good.
- Etc. There can be many other reasons to consider it good or bad.

**What should you do?** Create a list of quality aspects (time, cost, performance, etc.), decide how important is each them *in your particular* case. Then you will see how good is your approach compared to others.